# Efficient VBA coding

Tags: excel, vba

I've been having difficulty speeding up this line of VBA code but on a much larger scale.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim Names As String
Dim rownumber As Long

Names = Sheet1.Cells(5, 4)

'Attendance Tracker

Set rng = Sheet3.Columns("B:B").Find(What:=Names, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    On Error Resume Next
    rownumber = rng.Row
    
    'jan - completed
    
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 9).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 9).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 10).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 10).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 11).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 11).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 12).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 12).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 13).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 13).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 14).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 14).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 15).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 15).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 16).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 16).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 17).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 17).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 18).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 18).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 19).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 19).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 20).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 20).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 21).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 21).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 22).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 22).Value
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 23).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 23).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 9).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 24).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 10).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 25).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 11).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 26).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 12).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 27).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 13).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 28).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 14).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 29).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 15).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 30).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 16).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 31).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 17).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 32).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 18).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 33).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 19).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 34).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 20).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 35).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 21).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 36).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 22).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 37).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 23).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 38).Value
  Sheet1.Cells(13, 24).Value = Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 39).Value
```

I have this code running for the other 11 months so a I track attendance.

is there anyway to speed this up, or write it in a more functioning way?

Comment: `Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(8, 9),Sheet1.Cells(8, 23)).Value = Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 9),Sheet3.Cells(rownumber, 23)).Value` and do the same with the second group.

Answer (score 0):

To write it in a more functional way you can try the below.
This has not been tested as I do not have test data, but should get you close to what you need to do?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Names As String
    Dim rownumber As Long

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh3 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)

    Dim r() As Integer
    nRows = Array(8, 13)

    Names = sh1.Cells(5, 4)
    rownumber = SearchColumn(sh3.columns("B:B"))
    If rownumber = 0 Then End

    For Each row In nRows
        For col = 9 To 24
            col3 = col
            If (row = 8 And col = 24) Then Goto 100
            If row = 13 Then col3 = col3 + 15
            sh1.Cells(row, col).value = sh3.Cells(rownumber, col3).value
        Next
100:
    Next
End Sub

Function SearchColumn(rng As Range, argument As Variant) As Long
    'Please note that program 'management' by Error triggers is not ideal?
    Set fRng = rng.Find(What:=argument, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    If fRng Is Nothing Then
        SearchColumn = 0
    Else
        SearchColumn = fRng.row
    End If
    
End Function
```